# How to use $.ajax in WP custom function?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I am working with Wordpress and I want to use the jQuery `$.ajax()` function in my custom function.php file in child theme . I am new in WP so I don't have any ideas how to use jQuery AJAX in WP.

I have no idea what will be the URL of the function from where the JSON data will come. Please help

```html
<div class="rig-textGrid" style="cursor: pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="GetDetailsCat('.$cat_id.')">'.$name.'</div>
```

```js
function GetDetailsCat(cat_id) {
  data = "";
  url = "";
  data = "&cat_id=" + cat_id;
  url = "";

  $.ajax({
    data: data,
    type: "get",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    error: function(resp) {
      alert("Somthing Went Wrong !!!");
    },
    success: function(resp) {}
  });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _“in my custom.php file”_? Is this outside of WordPress, running completely independently? _“I am new in WP so I don't have any ideas how to use jQuery AJAX in WP.”_ - being new is not an _excuse_ … there are plenty of explanations how to use AJAX in WordPress out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this
You can write GetDetailsCat() in function.php

```
<?php  
function load_script_to_get_data(){
?>
<script>
function GetDetailsCat(cat_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
    dataType: "json",
    data : { action: "get_data", cat_id: cat_id }
    error: function(resp) {
      alert("Somthing Went Wrong !!!");
    },
    success: function(resp) {
    }
  });
}
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'load_script_to_get_data' );
```

Comment: there is a problem . when I display the response the whole page is displayed

Comment: can you explain more exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I want to get a json array in response . but when i alert the response its show the whole page not the json array

Answer (score 1):

Look for this solution. I think it will sure help you.
for run ajax in Wordpress in ajax URL you need to give admin-ajax URL which is admin_url('admin-ajax.php') 
next, you need to post an action in data which belongs to your functions.php's function

```
function GetDetailsCat(cat_id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
    dataType: "json",
    data : { action: "get_data", cat_id: cat_id }
    error: function(resp) {
      alert("Somthing Went Wrong !!!");
    },
    success: function(resp) {
    }
  });
}

functions.php 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_data', 'get_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'get_data' );
function get_data() {
    $cat_id= esc_attr ($_POST['cat_id ']);
    $result = "Your custom code which you want to do run";
    echo  $result; //return value
    die();
}
```

Comment: can I write GetDetailsCat() & get_data() both in function.php

Comment: Yes you can but for this, you need to make one more function in which you will put the script tag

Comment: how ? please explain

Comment: Please check my other answer for this.